# Is there a simple way to convert timestrings in bash?

Tags: bash

I often have to convert strings containing time in one format to another format - like:

```
time some_command
real    1m24.90s
user    0m0.01s
sys     0m0.00s
```

I could, with some effort, parse these time expressions in bash, or I could learn more awk and probably do it there, but it would be nice if there already exists some command. Am I to be disappointed?

***Edit:***

So, to clarify: I could of course just write a small piece of code, but I just imagined that there might already be something - perhaps something that would look like, which allows you to specify a the input- and output format:

```
$ tmconvert --in-fmt="%Sm%S" --out-fmt="%S" "1m24.90s"
```

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly you want to convert the strings to? These seem to me to all have the same format.

Comment: Well, yes, they are output by the time command; I would like to convert them to seconds, in the present case, but once they are in seconds it wouldn't be hard to convert to something different. I know how I can do it in some programming language, I just wondered if there already exists an convenient utility.

Answer (score 1):

You can use option `-p`  of time .

```
mbp:~ em444$ time -p sleep 120
real 120.01
user 0.00
sys 0.00
```

PS: usually you have 2 versions of `time`

- one is provided by your shell , so you must read `man bash` to have the documentation .
- the other `/usr/bin/time` , and you can the documentation by reading `man time`

Comment: Note: `-p` is [required by POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/time.html), so this solution should be highly portable.